# Bloom Filter in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, set, bitset, bloom-filter

I recently implemented a Bloom Filter in Haskell and, although I am not new to functional programming, I am a beginner when it comes to Haskell itself.

I'll gladly take any feedback regarding the implementation or the code style. I tried to stick to the Haskell conventions regarding function and variable naming, but I may have gotten some stuff wrong.

You will notice that I'm using my own implementation of a Bitset, you can assume it behaves like a normal one (I sure hope so).

```
module DataStructures.BloomFilter (empty, insert, member, DataStructures.BloomFilter.null) where

import System.Random (random, StdGen)
import qualified DataStructures.Bitset as Bitset
import Data.Hashable (hashWithSalt)

-- n: expected number of items in the Bloom Filter
-- p: acceptable probability of a false positive
-- m: max number of bits the Bloom Filter will use
-- k: number of hashing functions

data BloomFilter = BloomFilter {
  n :: Int, p :: Float, bitset :: Bitset.Bitset, m :: Int, k :: Int, hashSeed :: Int
} deriving (Eq, Show)

getMaxSize :: Int -> Float -> Int
getMaxSize n p = abs $ ceiling $ fromIntegral n * (log p) / (log (1 / (log 2 ^ 2)))

getNumberOfHashFunctions :: Int -> Int -> Int
getNumberOfHashFunctions n m = round $ fromIntegral (m `div` n) * log 2

empty :: Int -> Float -> StdGen -> BloomFilter
empty n p randGen =
  let m = getMaxSize n p
      k = getNumberOfHashFunctions n m
      hashSeed = fst $ random randGen
  in  BloomFilter n p Bitset.empty m k hashSeed

null :: BloomFilter -> Bool
null = Bitset.null . bitset

getHashes :: Show a => BloomFilter -> a -> [Int]
getHashes bloomFilter elem =
  let str     = show elem
      seed    = hashSeed bloomFilter
      maxSize = m bloomFilter
  in  (`mod` maxSize) . abs . (`hashWithSalt` str) . (seed +) <$> [1..(k bloomFilter)]

insert :: Show a => BloomFilter -> a -> BloomFilter
insert bloomFilter elem =
  let hashes    = getHashes bloomFilter elem
      newBitset = Bitset.insertMany (bitset bloomFilter) hashes
  in  bloomFilter { bitset = newBitset }

-- Returns whether an element *may be* present in the bloom filter.
-- This function can yield false positives, but not false negatives.
member :: Show a => BloomFilter -> a -> Bool
member bloomFilter elem =
  let hashes = getHashes bloomFilter elem
      bs     = bitset bloomFilter
  in  all (Bitset.member bs) hashes
```

I would have liked to use a murmur3 hashing function but all Haskell implementations use types that I'm not yet familiar with (Word32, ByteString).

Answer (score 3):

Instead of transforming everything to `String` using `Show` just for the purpose of hashing it, you should constraint element types to be [`Hashable`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/hashable-1.3.0.0/docs/Data-Hashable.html#t:Hashable) instead:

```
getHashes :: Hashable a => BloomFilter -> a -> [Int]
getHashes bloomFilter elem =
  let seed    = hashSeed bloomFilter
      maxSize = m bloomFilter
  in  (`mod` maxSize) . abs . (`hashWithSalt` elem) . (seed +) <$> [1..(k bloomFilter)]
```

I'd also use `maxSize` and `numFuns` as the field names in `BloomFilter` and then use `RecordWildCards`:

```
getHashes :: Hashable a => BloomFilter -> a -> [Int]
getHashes BloomFilter{..} elem = map nthHash [1..numFuns]
  where
    nthHash n = abs (hashWithSalt (n + hashSeed) elem) `mod` maxSize
```

Or maybe even nicer:

```
getHashes :: Hashable a => BloomFilter -> a -> [Int]
getHashes BloomFilter{..} elem = 
  [ abs (hashWithSalt (i + hashSeed) elem) `mod` maxSize  | i <- [1..numFuns] ]
```

Comment: Oh I did not know about the RecordWildCards thing. Very cool, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I only have one minor nitpick: the definition of `getMaxSize` becomes clearer if we use `logBase`:

```
abs $ ceiling $ fromIntegral n * (log p) / (log (1 / (log 2 ^ 2)))
```

becomes

```
abs $ ceiling $ fromIntegral n * (- 0.5) * logBase (log 2) p
```

We can use the identity `ceiling (-x) == - floor(x)` to get

```
abs . floor $ fromIntegral n * 0.5 * logBase (log 2) p
```